# How do I write this insert statement in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

```
newthing = Link(user=request.user,last_updated=datetime.datetime.now())
```

However, this uses datetime , not the MYSQL "now()".

How can I use mysql's now()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this uses the MySQL `now()` call, but the right way to do this in Django is to use the [`auto_now_add`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) or [`auto_add`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) options on a DateField/DateTimeField:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    ...
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    ...
```

Note: I am assuming here that `Link` is a Model.

Comment: For a field such as `last_updated`, `auto_now=True` will be the desirable argument to use.